# Ejecutar sentencia php sin conexión a internet

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Actualmente almaceno las imágenes en una carpeta especifica, esta sentencia la ejecuto desde un formulario php, el problema surge cuando este lleno el formulario de manera Offline, la sentencia php que envia la foto a la ruta especifica no se ejecuta, y quisiera saber si existe una forma de poder ejecutar esa sentencia php sin tener que instalar un sistema de gestion de base de datos , y sin conexión a internet, ya que este es uno de los requisitos principales

utilizo Laravel, Javascript, html, php

La sentencia que ejecuta php es esta.

```
<?php
;
    if (isset($_POST['imagenes'])){
        echo "si entre";
        $urlImagenElemento = $_POST['imagenes'];
        $identificador = $_POST['id'];
        for($i=0;$i<count($urlImagenElemento);$i++){
            if(strpos($urlImagenElemento[$i],'base64') == false){
                $imagenURLFondeoTransformada = 'data'.$urlImagenElemento[$i];
                $formato = explode(';base64,', $imagenURLFondeoTransformada[$i]);
                $formatoImg = explode('/',$formato[0]);
                $data = base64_decode($formato[1]);
                $letras = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
                $nombreAleatorio = str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
                $ubicacion = '/Users/usuario/Desktop/pruebaCreacionCarpeta/'.'id'. $identificador.'vuelta'.$i.'-'.$nombreAleatorio .'.'.$formatoImg[1];
                file_put_contents($ubicacion,$data);
            }else{
                $formato = explode(';base64,', $urlImagenElemento[$i]);
                $formatoImg = explode('/',$formato[0]);
                $data = base64_decode($formato[1]);
                $letras = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
                $nombreAleatorio = str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
                $ubicacion = '/Users/usuario/Desktop/pruebaCreacionCarpeta/'.'id'. $identificador. 'vuelta'.$i.'-'.$nombreAleatorio .'.'.$formatoImg[1];
                file_put_contents($ubicacion,$data);
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "hola no retorne";
    }

?>
```

las imagenes la convierto en base 64 en el formulario, y las envio en como arreglo en el $_POST['imagenes']

Comment: compártenos qué es lo que intentas ejecutar y cómo.

Comment: Editare la pregunta con la sentencia @Alfabravo

Comment: Gracias! Valdría la pena ver los logs de PHP para ver si sale algo. En principio, lo único con cara de problemático en tu código es la ruta, pues el servidor donde esté PHP no suele estar corriendo con el usuario cuya carpeta quieres modificar.

Comment: A qué te referís con "offline"? Literalmente desconectado de internet? A través de que URL accedes a la página? Si el sitio está en un servidor remoto, no vas a poder acceder sin estar conectado a internet. Si es un servidor local si, pero todo depende de cómo accedas.

Comment: Según tu código, si es eso solo lo que quieres ejecutar, no necesitas motor de base de datos (no se si laravel la necesita de saque, pero supongamos que no).  Lo que si necesitas es un servidor web con soporte de PHP y poner este script y el formulario php en el public de dicho servidor (o bien crearte un virtualhost para ello y ponerlo en su public). Suponiendo que todo eso lo tienes hecho... ¿cual es el error que obtienes al ejecutar el código de tu pregunta?  ¿o tu pregunta era eso que acabo de contestar?

Comment: Efectivamente solo es esto lo que quiero ejecutar, actualmente poseo un servidor web que soporte PHP, para ponerlos en contexto, este proyecto tiene la finalidad primero de funcionar de manera web, a su vez cuando esten en un lugar sin acceso a internet, podrán rellenar el formulario sin problema,  actualmente almaceno las vistas en cache, la info en IndexedDB que es la base de datos de el navegador, asi, al tener acceso a internet, a traves de un boton, se sincronizara toda esa info en la base de datos de el servidor

Comment: pero me surgieron problemas al almacenar las imagenes, ya que el formulario son mas imagenes que información, las almacenaba en base64 quedando una linea de texto exageradamente extensa, por lo que al momento de sincronizar, las imagenes no se podian procesar, ya que podían facilmente llegar a ser 500 imagenes, por lo que como solución, quise guardar las imagenes en una ruta especifica  del computador que este en uso(la que se ve en codigo es una ruta de prueba) con esto, en ve de la imagen, solo almaceno la ruta de dicha imagen, y asi a la hora de sincronizar, envio las imagenes al servidor

Comment: gracias por la explicación, es interesante... ¿pero cual es el error que te da el código y en que necesitas ayuda?

Comment: A nivel de lógica y código no da ningún error , solo necesito saber si existe alguna forma que esa sentencia php se ejecute sin tener acceso a internet , o en caso de no existir alguna solución , alguna función de javascript , dónde pueda almacenar una imagen en una ruta específica, o algo similar , en pocas palabras , no tener que almacenar temporalmente la imagen en base 64 @masterguru

Comment: no acabo de entenderte... creia que cuando decias esto `actualmente poseo un servidor web` te referias a un servidor local en el dispositivo donde quieres ejecutar ese código.  Con eso ya no necesitas internet, lo ejecutas en locahost y andando.  Si por otro lado lo quieres ejecutar desde terminal pues supongo que puedes instalarte tan solo el interprete de PHP y ejecutarlo directamente via comando.  Y si mucho me apuras, sólo con el interpréte de PHP puedes lanzar un servicio que hace un simulacro de servidor web sin tener que instalarte todo un apache o lo que sea que pueda correr en local

Comment: eso que acabo de decirte sobre el servidor web solo usando el intérprete de PHP, lo encontrarás [en este enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php)